# ITunes Connect refuses Frameworks or SharedFrameworks directories

Tags: frameworks, app-store-connect, swift2, xcode7

I want to embed two private frameworks in my app. All are in swift, with bridges to obj-c to one external framework from Parse.com.

I have to manually delete the Frameworks directory to be able to upload my project to iTunes Connect.

Do I miss something here ?

Answer (score 0):

It goes well after I uncheck 'Include app symbols' (checked by default) before submitting.
But I don't understand why...

Comment: Faced the same issue but with my own frameworks. Unchecking the 'Include app symbols' doesn't help.

Comment: Strange. I disabled bitcode in my frameworks and client project also. Still it's not crystal clear...